# Erro de MaxRequestLen ao fazer upload de ficheiros

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

Estou a trabalhar em PHP e a fazer *upload* de ficheiros, ao tentar fazer um *upload* de 60M obtenho o seguinte erro:

> mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 16784592 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen
>   (16777216)

Tenho o meu ficheiro de configuração `/etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf` assim configurado:

```
... 
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
MaxRequestLen 1073741824
...
```

E tenho o `php.ini` com

```
upload_max_filesize = 2048M
post_max_size = 2048M
```

Já pesquisei por todo lado e não encontro nenhuma resolução para esse erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diretiva [FcgidMaxRequestLen](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestlen) define o comprimento máximo do corpo de uma Requisição. De acordo com [a documentação](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestlen) do módulo essa diretiva tem como padrão 131072 bytes e que antes da versão 2.3.6 essa diretiva tinha como padrão 2GB.

Dito isso você precisa reconfigurar esse valor, seja diretamente no servidor (*httpd.conf*) ou no arquivo de configuração do(s) seu(s) VirtualHosts (normalmente, *vhost.conf*) haja vista, de acordo [com um stack do ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/269859), esse tipo de alteração não ser possível de ser feita no escopo de um simples *.htaccess*.

Vale salientar ainda que essas medidas são complementares aquelas relativas à upload de arquivos feitas no PHP.INI.

Comment: É mesmo isso @Bruno Augusto, resultou a alteração no vhost.conf. Obrigado

Comment: Que bom que pude ajudar :)